# git-bash if else fails on certain scenarios

Tags: git-bash

im running below code on windows git bash .

```
createDirectory() {

if [[ -d $1 ]]
then
  cd   $1
else
  mkdir -p  $1 
  fi
}

createDirectory "process1" 
createDirectory "process2" 
createDirectory "process3" 
createDirectory "process4"
```

it creates 4 folders on first run .if i delete a folder say **rm -rf process3** and  and try to rerun the script fails to check and create the folder that was deleted .why ? I tried elif instead of else still had same issue.

Comment: You called cd if the directory exists, hence the folder is created in "process1" when you rerun.

Comment: hey thanks i got it it was a mistake i dint realise it